# What does it mean that something is vary from machine to machine?

Tags: c

Sometimes when reading books, Like The C Programming Language, The author talk about that number and types of register variables vary from machine to machine.

Comment: Do you really think that your iPad Pro has the same type of chips, memory, and operating system as your dad's IBM AT from the 1980s? But both can compile C. That's the beauty of C: you can use it on many different machines. That's what the books talk about.

Comment: The author is speaking about different *CPU types*, that's all.

Comment: Hardware, operating system and other software might be different from one system to another. They [*vary*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are hundreds of different CPU architecture with different instructions, register numbers and length etc.

With regards to C, it is machine dependent how for example an `int` is represented. Most architecture treat it as 32 bit integer, but others may as 64 bit, so there are machine dependent aspects.

Comment: "Most architecture treat it as 32 bit integer". At the time of writing I'd be willing to place a bet on the majority of chips running C programs having a 16 bit `int`.

Comment: You willing to take the other side of my bet? As a final word of caution, don't forget about all those embedded systems out there.

Comment: Yes I would. But I feel you mainly think about MCUs.

Comment: But yes if we nitpicking, it maybe most accurate to say "Most architecture you will encounter."

Comment: Although then you might hurt the feelings of an embedded systems guy, and they are the *real* programmers out there.

Comment: I also do embedded programming at this very moment. Embedded programming is not limited to 8/16 bit architectures which mostlikely treat it as 16 bit.

Comment: The main reasons you would be *likely* to see a difference nowadays are: 32-bit vs 64-bit, Windows vs Linux, PCs vs cellphones/tablets, and sometimes different compilers.

Comment: @Bathsheba is right - At the time "The C Programming Language" was written, the majority of CPUs provided a 16-bit integer, not a 32-bit integer.   Historically, it is also true that more CPUs supported 16-bit integers then 32-bit.     In fact, some 32-bit CPU architectures provided 16-bit "native" integers.